# Changing a variable on click based on number of elements - jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, variables

I wrote a script of my portfolio, which works almost how I want it, but I'd like to make it so I don't ever have to edit the script, just the HTML.

The code basically needs to do this:

1. Count how many `<img>` tags are within `#thumbs`
2. Take the `SRC` from the thumb, or an `HREF` if possible from an A tag around the thumb
3. Place either the `SRC` (subtracting _sm from the file name), or `HREF` in a variable

After that I think I can figure out how to make it functional. I just don't know how to make the script read the information and change based on that. Once I have the variables set up I should be able to figure it out pretty easily.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // the last thumbnail I clicked on
            var last = "idthisperson";

            // variables based on IDs
            // this meathod is too sloppy in my opinion
            var graphic01 = "idthisperson";
            var graphic02 = "leo";
            var graphic03 = "water-fire";

            // my test of counting how many
            // img tags are within #thumbs
            var n = $("#thumbs img").length;        
            alert(n);

            // seperate functions based on the img ID
            // that you clicked on. Would like one function.
            $("#" + graphic01).click(function() {
                if(last != graphic01) {
                    $("#placeholder").before( "<img src=\"gallery/" + graphic01 + ".jpg\" />" );
                    $("#mask").css("marginTop","-=450px");
                    last = graphic01;
                }
            });

            $("#" + graphic02).click(function() {
                if(last != graphic02) {
                    $("#placeholder").before( "<img src=\"gallery/" + graphic02 + ".jpg\" />" );
                    $("#mask").css("marginTop","-=450px");
                    last = graphic02;
                }
            });

            $("#" + graphic03).click(function() {
                if(last != graphic03) {
                    $("#placeholder").before( "<img src=\"gallery/" + graphic03 + ".jpg\" />" );
                    $("#mask").css("marginTop","-=450px");
                    last = graphic03;
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

And the HTML:

```
   <section id="portfolio">
    <section id="mask">
        <img src="gallery/idthisperson.jpg" />
        <div id="placeholder"></div>
    </section><!--/#mask-->
</section><!--/#portfolio-->
<section id="thumbs">
    <a href="gallery/idthisperson.jpg"><img id="idthisperson" src="gallery/idthisperson_sm.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="gallery/leo.jpg"><img id="leo" src="gallery/leo_sm.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="galelry/water-fire.jpg"><img id="water-fire" src="gallery/water-fire_sm.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="gallery/idthisperson.jpg"><img src="gallery/idthisperson_sm.jpg" /></a>
</section><!--/#thumbs-->
```

EDIT: Live demo: http://beta.jacobbearce.com/portfolio.htm
EDIT 2: How do I use the `transitionend` bit of javascript to make sure my CSS3 transition is complete before clicking the next thumbnail works?
EDIT 3: Viewing the source on the live demo would be best to see the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create one function that would work with any <strike>`<img>`</strike> `<a>` tag in the thumbs div by using the <strike>ID</strike> href of the <strike>image</strike> link as the name of the graphic.

```
$("#thumbs a").click(function() {
    var graphic = $(this).attr('href'); //get the href of the anchor
    if(last != graphic) {
        $("#placeholder").before( "<img src=\"" + graphic + "\" />" );
        $("#mask").css("marginTop","-=450px");
        last = graphic;
    }
    return false; //makes the browser not redirect the user
});
```

EDIT: changed my code to match the edit of the original question.

Comment: Ah, thanks I'll try this out, too. Unfortunately I'm working right now so I won't be able to test for about 4 hours.

Comment: After looking at this closer, this look like it answers the last of my questions. I'm pretty  sure this will work :) Thanks.

Comment: It's still redirecting to the other page :/

Comment: AHA! Okay, so the one thing missing from this was that you have to give the variable "last" an initial value (in my case, ""). This script works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 1):

**1. Count how many  tags are within #thumbs**

```
numOfImgTags = $('#thumbs img').length;
```

**2. Take the SRC from the thumb, or an HREF if possible from an A tag around the thumb**

```
imgSrc = $('#thumbs img').attr('src');
aHref = $('#thumbs img').parent('a').attr('href');
```

**3. Place either the SRC (subtracting _sm from the file name), or HREF in a variable**

```
imgSrcVariable = imgSrc.replace('_sm','');
//the aHref variable above already does this
```

Is that enough to get you going?

Comment: Ahh! Thanks, this looks perfect. I'll try it when I get home from work tonight :)

Comment: I had a bit of time to try it just now, and I think it'd work, but how do I disable the link to the new image from redirecting the whole page?

Comment: You'll have to explain further what you're trying to do. Do you want to do a jQuery lightbox kind of thing, where clicking the link fetches the image via AJAX and then presents it over the rest of the page? i.e. http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: No, I put a live demo link in the question: http://beta.jacobbearce.com/portfolio.htm which shows what I'm trying to do. It works on that site, but you have to write in a seperate function for each thumb, which isn't ideal.

Comment: I guess I'm not clear on how you're using the code. For example, the code you posted above doesn't even have any <a> tags. So I'm not sure what is causing a page redirection.

Comment: Ah, sorry, the new code does. I'll edit it to reflect that. I basically want the HREF to do nothing, but be a placeholder for the URL, whithin #thumbs.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to have just one function that works on all thumbs take a look at my answer. It should just take the href from the `<a>` and use that to run the pull up script thingy that you already have.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var n=0;
var images=[];
$('#thumbs img').each(function(){
    n=n+1; //increase the number of images
    images[n]=$(this).attr('src').replace('_sm',''); //we place the src in the appropriate index, i left the 0 index without value just to avoid confusion
});
```

now for the immage number x you can access the source by using : images[x];

hope this will help